# Как узнать количество оставшейся памяти в куче?

Tags: c++, c, windows, qt

Хочу узнать в ходе работы программы количество памяти в куче. Пишу в QT на c++, ОС Windows 10. Возможно есть какие-то встроенные функции для этого? Если же нет, то как это можно реализовать ?

Comment: Ну дело-то в том, что память может и свопиться, например... Так что это несколько, гм, абстрактная величина. В свое время у Саттера в какой-то из его книжек хорошо описывалось, что такое выяснение особого смысла не имеет...

Comment: ¿А зачем вам это понадобилось? ¿Это случаем не проблема XY? Также "узнать количество оставшейся памяти" очень сильно отличается от "узнать в ходе работы программы количество памяти в куче".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Единственный способ *надежно* узнать, сколько есть свободной **физической памяти** - это залочить ([увеличить WorkingSet](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/increase-a-process-working-set), потом [VirtualAlloc](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-virtualalloc), затем [VirtualLock](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-virtuallock)) ее и посмотреть, получилось ли.

Потому что в противном случае, может выйти неприятная ситуация - вы узнали у системы, сколько у нее физической ([GetMemoryStatusEx](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/win32/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-globalmemorystatusex?redirectedfrom=MSDN)) памяти, но между "узнаванием" и реальной работой (физические страницы будут выделены только тогда, когда вы реально станете в них писать, а не при вызове `new`) пришла какая-то программа и память вкусно скушала.

Это все имеет смысл делать, когда ваша программа работает на машине пользователя преимущественно монопольно - например, это игра, или хайлоад какой-нибудь. В противном случае, как верно заметил @Harry - овчинка выделки не стоит.

Comment: лет 20 назад была одна программа, которая именно так и делала. Вот только отладчику делфи это очень-очень не нравилось. А сама программа так и осталась в небытии.

Comment: Добавил название функции в ответ